# How to fix incorrect cutoff frequency using multiple feedback butterworth lowpass filter

Tags: design, active-filter, troubleshooting

I designed a 6th order low pass Butterworth filter using multiple feedback topology (Fc = 500 Hz). But when I run it in LTSpice, the cutoff frequency is seen shifted far below to around 10Hz. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it? Any comments or references to reading material are greatly appreciated. I apologize if I did not ask the question in the best format, first time on here.

[image: I am looking to accomplish a 6th order low pass filter using multiple feedback]
[image: Here the topology I am using]

Comment: You are aware, I hope, that the polynomial table you have above is based upon \$\omega_{_0}=1\$, yes?

Comment: You need to scale the prototype figures for both impedance and frequency (radians/s, not Hz). Show us the figures/calculations you have for one section, from prototype numbers through to component values.

Comment: Here is another tipp for the design: There are two simplifications - either you can choose (a) R2=R3=R or you can (from the beginning) choose (b) two standard capacitors  with C2/C1>4*Qp²(1+R2/R1).

Comment: @LvW I'd go for (b) as capacitor values have fewer options. It's easier to identify the capacitors you have and are appropriate and then let the resistors fall out from that decision.

Comment: Jonk - yes, that is the reason I have mentioned this design alternative.

Comment: @jonk yeah that is why I am going with multiple feedback rather than sallen-key for LP. I want to be able to choose capacitors.

Comment: @pdxstudent Sallen-Key does not require equal capacitor values. Have you read their paper?

Comment: @jonk I think that is the problem. I did not realize that Wo is 1 rad/s for that table. Guess I need to do some scaling

Comment: @pdxstudent Yup. All filters can be fully analyzed with the simplification of setting that to 1. It just makes it more confusing to do otherwise. Then you just rescale afterwards.